# Cannot get data from the api

Tags: reactjs, axios

Trying to fetch data from API but could not able to as I am new to reactjs and having trouble in
fetching data for making a project of cryptocurrency tracker.

How can I use axios to fetch data and also want to know how to handle error using try catch method

Code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
    getData = () => {
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest",
            qs: {
                start: "1",
                limit: "100",
                convert: "USD"
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "api_key"
            },
            json: true
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    render() {
        return <div>hello asfa</div>;
    }
}
```

Getting the following error:-

> Uncaught error (in promise) - at createError (createError.js:16)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError

Comment: try adding a `.catch((error)=>{ console.log(error)})` after your `.then ` and see if it prints anything?

Answer (score 0):

Hello firstly every call api should go into componentDidMount and you have to save it somewhere so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  curr: ""
};


}

async getData = () => {
await axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest',
  qs: {
    'start': '1',
    'limit': '100',
    'convert': 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'my_key'
  },
  json: true
}).then((response) => {
    this.setState({
          curr: response.data
    });
  console.log(response);
})
}

componentWillMount(){
  this.getData();
}

render(){
  return (
    <div>
     {this.state.curr}
    </div>
   )
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-implemented your component using state and async await with try catch block:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      apiResponse: {},
      url: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest', // <- API URL
    }
  }

  async getData() {
    try {
      const response = await axios({ // <- Asynchronous API request. Saves axios' response on a constant;
        url: this.state.url, // <- Using Component's state's url;
        method: 'GET',
        qs: {
          'start': '1',
          'limit': '100',
          'convert': 'USD'
        },
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'api_key'
        },
        json: true
      });

      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ apiResponse: response }); // <- Saving api response in Component's state;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      this.setState({ error }); // <- If an error occurred it will be saved on Component's state;
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData(); // <- Call API
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello World!
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```